# Making custom layouts on PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I've created 4 different interfaces on QtDesigner and I want to connect them with buttons. As far as I researched, the way to do this is creating layouts for each interface and connect them with QStackedWidget or QStackedLayouts.

But I didn't use any defined layout methods, I directly converted my code from ui to py, thus all buttons, labels are placed with using geometry manager (with setGeometry method)

I've summarized my code and applied QHBoxLayout for instance and it worked. But I don't want to use any defined method for layout management I just want to create an empty layout for each interface and add all buttons, labels into this empty layout with their spesific geometric locations.

I've tried QtWidgets.QLayout but it pops up an error message which is:

```
TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLayout represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
```

I've created below interface with simply dragging and dropping the buttons&labels in QTDesigner
[image: Interface that I want to create]

and with using python QGridLayout manager, I've created this:
[image: Interface that I created with Layout Manager (using QGridLayout)]

How will I create a custom layout for each of my interfaces to add all of my buttons, labels etc. created by using "setGeometry" method

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added some screenshots to explain

Comment: @omrakn If you use a layout you will not be able to use setGeometry, so there are 2 options: you manage the geometry or a layout does it. Why don't you use QVBoxLayout?

Comment: @omrakn If you don't want to use layouts, then don't use them. Why do you think you need an "empty" layout? A stacked-widget does not require layouts.

Comment: Because all of the examples I saw used this method. I actually created a post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989216/switching-frames-in-pyqt?noredirect=1#comment100534417_56989216" for my main problem and in all of the answers and resources from the web, they used layouts for switching frames.

Comment: @omrakn That's because layouts are by far the best way of creating easily maintainable GUIs. You ***can*** use fixed sizes and absolute poistioning, but that usually creates a lot of unnecessary problems. Qt is designed to work best with layouts, so I would advise that you learn how to use them properly and stop trying to swim against the tide.

Comment: yeah, then I will try to construct it with creating grids, forms etc. Cheers mate!